# How to set array value in twig template

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

How I can change my array value by string index in twig template? I'm trying:

```
{% do params['redirect_uri'] = 'http://site.loc/' %}
```

but I get nex error:

```
Unexpected token "operator" of value "=" ("end of statement block" expected) in
BWUserBundle:User/social:sign-in-thumbs.html.twig at line 4
```

I also trying:

```
{% set params['redirect_uri'] = 'http://site.loc/' %}
```

but have error too:

```
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "[" ("end of statement block" expected) in 
BWUserBundle:User/social:sign-in-thumbs.html.twig at line 4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about,

```
{% set params = params|merge({'redirect_uri': 'http://site.loc/'}) %}
```

Comment: `Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block" expected) in BWUserBundle:User/social:sign-in-thumbs.html.twig at line 4`