# Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "["

Tags: php, twig

My twig code

```
{% for language in languages %} 
{% if (menu_new[language.language_id] is defined) %} {% set menu_new[language.language_id] = "text" %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

my PHP code

```
foreach ($languages as $language) {
if(!isset($menu_new[$language['language_id']])) $menu_new[$language['language_id']]        = "text";
}
```

i have this error : 
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "["

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set array value in twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113197/how-to-set-array-value-in-twig-template)

Comment: Note that the two codes don't do the same thing: PHP uses `!isset()` while Twig uses `is defined`. It should probably be `is not defined`.